# Considerations for python gui toolkit for app that queries remote database?

Tags: python, tkinter, wxpython, pyqt, pygtk

I know this question has been asked before but those questions typically lack specific details and result in answers that say something like "It depends what you are trying to do..." so the main gist of this app is that it retrieves remote data (ex. text) and object (ex. images).

Since PHP and python are the two programming languages I feel comfortable with I felt python was more suited for desktop gui apps.  I'm creating a desktop music player and here are some of the technical specs I want to include:

- A sign in construct that authenticates user credentials  (Like
  spotify, skype, league of legends) against a remote database (This
  will be in mysql.)  My thinking is to create a web api for the client to query via HTTP/HTTPS GET/POST
- A client side SQLite database that stores the filename, filepath and
  id3 tags of the song so upon launching, the application displays each song in a row with the song length, artist, album, genre (Like iTunes)
- Retrieve remote images and display them within the application's frame (Like skype displays a person's profile picture.)
- Must be cross-platform (At least in Windows and Mac), look native in different OS's but the native look and feel should be easily overridden with custom styles (Ex. rounded buttons with gradients.)
- Compilation for Windows and Mac should be relatively straightforward

Of the popular python gui toolkits like PyQt, PyGTK, Tkinter, wxPython, Pyjamas, PyGObject and PySide which are well suited for my application and why?  Why are the others not well suited for these specs?    Which have good documentation and active communities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to a *fun* area:

1. Watch out for urllib2:  it doesn't check the certificate or the certificate chain.  Use requests instead or use ssl library and check it yourself.  See [Urllib and validation of server certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648952/urllib-and-validation-of-server-certificate)  Sometimes a little ZeroMQ (0mq) can simplify your server.
2. You should consider shipping a self signed certificate with your application if you are a private server/private client pair.  At that point, validating the certificate eliminates a host of other possible problems.
3. While you could read a lot about security issues, like [Crypto 101](https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/crypto-101-by-laurens-van-houtven), the short version is use TLS (the new name for SSL) to transmit the data and GPG to store the data.  TLS keeps others from seeing and altering the data when moving it.  GPG keeps others from seeing and altering the data when storing or retreiving it.  See also: [How to safely keep a decrypted temporary data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010088/how-to-safely-keep-a-decrypted-temporary-data)  Enough about security!
4. SqlLite3, used with gpg, is fine until you get too large.  After that, you can move to MariaDB (the supported version of MySQL), PostGreSQL, or something like Mongo.   I'm a proponent of [doing things that don't scale](http://paulgraham.com/ds.html) and getting something working now is worthwhile.
5. For the GUI, you'll hate my answer:  HTML/CSS/JavaScript.  The odds that you will need a portal or mobile app or remote access or whatever are compelling.  Use jQuery (or one of its lightweight cousins like Zepto).  Then run your application as a full screen application without a browser bar or access to other sites.  You can use libraries to emulate the native look and feel, but customers almost always go "oh, I know how to use that" and stop asking.
6. Still hate the GUI answer?  While you could use Tcl/Tk or Wx but you will forever be fighting platform bugs.  For example, OS/X (Mac) users need to install ActiveState's Tcl/Tk instead of the default one.  You will end up with a heavy solution for the images (PIL or ImageMagick) instead of just the HTML image tag.  There is a huge list of other GUIs to play with, including some using the new 'yield from' construct.  Still, you do better with HTML/CSS/JavaScript for now.  Watch the "JavaScript: the Good Parts" and then adopt an attitude of ship it as it works.
7. Push hard to use either Python 2,7 or Python 3.3+.   You don't want to be fighting the rising tide of better support when you making a complicated application.

I do this stuff for FUN!

Answer (score 3):

### GUI library

First of all, please leverage the work people have done to compile [this GuiProgramming list](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming).

One one the packages that stood out to me was [`Kivy`](http://kivy.org/#home). You should definitely check it out (at least the videos / intro). The `Kivy` project has some [nice
 introduction](http://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/intro.html). I have to say I haven't followed it in full but it looks very promising. As for your requirements to be cross-platforms you can do that.

### Packaging

There is [an extensive documentation on how to package your app](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging.html) for the different platforms. For `MacOSX` and `Windows` it uses [`PyInstaller`](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki), but there are instructions for `Android` and `iOS`.

### Client-side database

Yes, [`sqlite3`](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) is the way to go. You can use `sqlite3` with `Kivy`. You can also use [`SQLAlchemy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/intro.html#installation) if you need to connect to your sqlite database or if you need to connect to a remote one.

### Retrieving content

The [`requests` library is awesome](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to do http requests and IMHO is much simpler to use than a combination of `httplib`, `urllib2`.

Answer (score 2):

Both PySide and WxPython support all five of your requirements. WxPython uses actual native widgets and also has custom extensions and widgets built on top. It has goodies like `wx.CallAfter` which'll allow you to run your background tasks in a separate thread and hop back on the UI thread easily.

PySide has a nicer API but draws its own widgets that imitate the underlying OS's UI. It's not as mature as WxPython and packaging it with tools like `cx_freeze` and `PyInstaller` is slightly more involved.

Also I recommend that you use an ORM like `peewee` over plain Sqlite3 for the data storage, it makes managing the data a lot easier and plays well with the freezing tools.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the answer always remains; it depends on your needs and wants, but putting that aside I would say; go with Qt/QML. Qt with QML has been gaining a lot of traction lately, and with [PyQt5 just release](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/news/pyqt-50), it definitely seems like a good and future-proof option. It is cross platform, easy to work with and supports theming.

I highly recommend you watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdljU3j67Qc) in which they seem to do exactly what you want. In less than an hour they build a simple application that retrieves data (including images) from an outside source and list them on screen. It is also easy to make responsive applications (scaling easily to different screen sizes).

Lastly, I don't know what your license requirements are. PyQt is licensed either under the GPL, or under a commercial license. So if your application is open source, PyQt is perfectly fine. If your application will be proprietary you'dd be better off using PySide, which is LGPL.

Good luck!

Comment: Well, I might go with Qt over Wx and certainly over Glade.  The Glade community failed hard when it mixed up its procedural driven API with its GladeML mark up language.   Perhaps Qt/QML will not suffer this fate.  Really, these are all larger versions of the basic libraries students create in a semester long class.  See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/mac-differences.html for an example of what each platform will be different.   For all users, the combination of PyQt GPLV3 (not 2!) license but with total control by one long running group is not a good mix.

Answer (score 0):

I only got expirience with Qt-based Python GUI-toolkits, and found them to be very powerful, well documented and simple to use (as long as you stay away from model-view framework). And they can do all the things you mentioned. So my recomendation would be PyQt or PySide. PySide's advantage is it's license - LGPL, so if your stuff is proprietary - go for PySide. PySide has some troubles however, as it is basically abandoned as of writing this, so you will have to dodge some bugs (nothing realy critical IMO). PyQt is more actively maintained and developed, but it's GPL or commercial (about 400 euros). So if your stuff is free, you should choose PyQt. And yes, use ORM, if possible. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: PySide isn't abandoned. They just had a sprint a last month.

Comment: Yes, and they've just released 1.2. Glad to be wrong about it.

Comment: I think they've been trying to figure out how to support QT 5 lately.

Comment: Wow. *That* would be great. But I've seen no mention of it in the mailing list. Is there another place the devs hang out at?

Comment: I saw it on the mailing list, although it was an older post. They also hang out in IRC.